# How to initialize List datamember in web service?

Tags: c#, datacontract, datamember

I have a List string datamember in a class in web service:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceOrder
{
   List<string> blList= new List<string>();
   [DataMember]
   public List<string> AuditStatus 
   {
        get { return blList; }
        set { blList = value; } 
   } 
}
```

I want to assign values or add values to that list in client code I am getting error:

```
ServiceOrder so = new ServiceOrder();
so.AuditStatus[0] = "Test";
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   I searched and tried many suggestions but nothing solved this issue, please help me solve this. Thanks

Comment: How can you reference an element in a list at any index if you don't have any objects in the list?

Comment: You need to have an method in the class "Serviceorder" to add elements to the list